# How to create a static library using swift 4?

Tags: swift4, xcode10

I would like to know how I can create a Cocoa touch static library using swift 4. I searched in several places but just found vague information. Help me please!

Comment: bro did you find any solution??

Comment: Hello Jeeva, after searching a lot, I ended up developing a cocoa touch framework and not a static library

Answer (score 0):

Simple sum step to create Cocoa touch static library.

- Step 01: create a new Xcode project.
- Step 02: Chose a template -> iOS -> Framework & Library -> Cocoa - Touch Static Library then click next.
- Step 03: Write your Library Project name and set our other info then click next.
- Step 04: chose your library project location then lick Save.
- Step 05: write your logic what dose library project.
- Step 06: go to Product menu then click Build Library project.
- Step 07: after build your see Your left navigator under product see your libraryName.a file this file move your project the used your library project.

Note: If your not clear please see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMYxlkOE35k&t=5s 
I think help you.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, I think I was not so clear in the question, I'm sorry, I was able to generate the .a, but how do I integrate it into my project and use library methods? In Objc's case a header is generated for this, but swift does not generate header file ...